# How do I use binaries from Conan packages?

Tags: c++, emscripten, conan

I'm trying build a project using Emscripten installed form the Conan center. I've been able to get it working, but I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to use the binaries for building my project.

Here's my conanfile:

```
[requires]
libxml2/2.10.3
zlib/1.2.13
zstd/1.5.2

[generators]
cmake
```

And my host profile:

```
[settings]
os=Emscripten
arch=wasm
compiler=clang
compiler.version=16
build_type=Release

[build_requires]
emsdk/3.1.23

[options]
libxml2:ftp=False
libxml2:shared=False
libxml2:threads=False
[env]
```

I thought I could use imports, but that didn't seem to work. Binaries from libxml and zstd got imported, but not anything from emsdk.

I eventually found a solution using conan info + awk:

```
source $(conan info  . --package-filter emsdk/3.1.23 --paths --only "package_folder" -pr:h emscripten -pr:b default 2>/dev/null | awk ' $2 != "" {print $2}')/bin/emsdk_env.sh
export PATH=$PATH:$(conan info  . --package-filter nodejs/16.3.0 --paths --only "package_folder" -pr:h emscripten -pr:b default 2>/dev/null |  awk ' $2 != "" {print $2}')/bin
```

But I feel like there's got to be a simpler way that I've just missed somehow.

Comment: There is an official documentation explaining its usage: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/cross_platform/emscripten.html
The emsdk package will configure both `CC` and `CXX` variables, so CMake will use `emcc` and `emc++` as compilers. Your generated binary will be cached in conan cache folder, but if you want to make it available in another place, you can customize the `--install-folder`, or after building, you can use `conan install -g deploy` to install only those binaries.Info [Deploy generator](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/deploy.html?highlight=deploy)

Comment: Their example seems outdated, I had to update the version of emsdk used to get it to work. But it seems like I have to use a conanfile.py rather than a txt file if I want to use the build tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use them by switching to the python config format.

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake


class SFCFEDecompress(ConanFile):
    description = ""
    license = "MIT"
    settings = {"os": ["Emscripten"]}
    exports_sources = ["./*"]
    generators = ["cmake"]

    def _configure_cmake(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure(source_folder=".")
        return cmake

    def build(self):
        cmake = self._configure_cmake()
        cmake.build()
        cmake.install()
```

After this I run install with my profile and then run conan build.

Strange that this is a requirement since the txt format is supposed to be sufficient for package consumers, but c'est la vie I guess.

Comment: This example is outdated and should be replaced by CMakeToolchain + cmake_layout instead. Please, read https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/migrating_to_2.0/recipes.html#the-layout-method for more information.